# How to upgrade macOS when it asks me to approve my billing info?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, upgrade, billing

I have a `mid 2012` macbook pro. I just wiped my mac HD and reinstalled macOS 10.8 mountain lion. Now I am trying to upgrade from mountain lion to high sierra. When I click the get button for high sierra in the app store it says:

```
Please click Billing Info to approve your billing information for use
in the iTunes Store. If you cancel you will not be able to buy until
you have approved your billing information.
```

And then when I proceed it says:

```
To make changes to your payment information, you need to upgrade your
Mac to the latest version of macOS.
```

How can I get out of this chicken and egg issue and upgrade my macOS?

I tried updating my billing info via the apple store website and then restarting my mac but that didn't change the above situation.

Comment: Try doing it online at appleid.apple.com or on your phone

Comment: Try using a different device, for example an iPhone or even an apple tv

Answer (score -1):

I had exactly the same problem on my early 2013 macbook pro with mac os Mountain Lion. For me, opening my Apple Id on my Ipad and changing the billing info there solved the problem.